# How to create spinner in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I am looking for spinner in wicket which should be simillar as JSpinner in java swing. I found class: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/wicketstuff/minis/1.4.9/minis-1.4.9-javadoc.jar!/org/wicketstuff/minis/spinner/Spinner.html in wicket minis stuff but I didint find any documentation how to use it in html code. I try to add minis example in my maven but with no success:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
        <artifactId>minis-examples</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

there is still `Missing artifact org.wicketstuff:minis-examples:jar:1.4.9.2:compile`
Is there other class with good documentation where is spinner ?

UPDATE:

I try something like this:

```
TextField<Integer> text = new TextField<Integer>("skupina");
Spinner spinner = new Spinner() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void configure(Properties p) {
        p.put("min", 1);
        super.configure(p);
    }
};
text.add(spinner);
add(text);
```

but I dont know  where is the mistake because I didnt find any example. Thuis throw me exception:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.wicket.Component.getResponse()Lorg/apache/wicket/Response;
    at org.wicketstuff.minis.spinner.Spinner.beforeRender(Spinner.java:152)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.notifyBehaviorsComponentBeforeRender(Component.java:3486)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2368)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2297)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Spinner` class defines not a component, but a component's behavior.

As stated in the [wicketstuff-minis Javadoc](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/wicketstuff/minis/1.4.9/minis-1.4.9-javadoc.jar!/org/wicketstuff/minis/spinner/Spinner.html#configure%28java.util.Properties%29)

> This behavior is used to augment a [`TextField`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/TextField.html) with spinning abilities.
>   For customization of the Spinner take a look at the [`configure(Properties)`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/wicketstuff/minis/1.4.9/minis-1.4.9-javadoc.jar!/org/wicketstuff/minis/spinner/Spinner.html#configure%28java.util.Properties%29) method.

I have never used this, but it seems, you just need to instantiate a *normal* wicket `TextField`, a and [add properly configured spinner behavior](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#add%28org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehavior...%29) to it.

Comment: behaviour or component I need some example where I can inspired.

Comment: I'd start with this: 1. Create a simple wicket page, with a textfield on it. There are plenty examples on the web. 2. Add a spinner behaviour to it, and see what gets generated in the HTML (probably some Javascript should appear). 3. Inspect `Spinner` code for details.

Comment: What version of Wicket are you using?

Comment: It seems, some wicket JAR files must me of different version, or missing from your execution environment. This method is there in version 1.5.x, so it looks like one of those voodoo exceptions.

Comment: Use WicketStuff-Minis 1.5.5 with Wicket 1.5.5. Don't mix major versions!